# why supreport overlapped by page header in ireport?

Tags: jasper-reports

I design a report in iReport with windows + weblogic, and there is a page header and detail column, and I place a subreport in the detail column.
It works well in windows + weblogic!
But when I deploy it to linux + weblogic, I found that whenever there is a new page in Detail column, the subreport content in detail column will be overlapped by page header.  It seems that when it create a new page, it can not realize the position of page header.

I have set the subreport's "Position type" to float, but don't work while everything is OK in windows + weblogic.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem. I finally rearranged the columns and I made it work fine in Linux.
Then it worked fine in windows also. I don't know if there exists a solution for this.

Comment: how to you rearrange the columns ? Can you describe it ??

Comment: I mean resizing the bands in main report and the columns in the subreport.

Comment: Sorry, How to resize the band  and the columns ? Do you mean add a blank in front of the subreport ?

Comment: Nope. If you are using ireport tool you can resize the bands using simple mouse dragging. Or you can increase the height in the Band properties also.

Comment: I increased the height of detail band, but it was still overlapped by the column header and page header.

Comment: Ok.. You have to see which portion is getting overlapping with other.
If the detail bad content is overlapping with the page header then try to increase the height of the detail bad. If you still persists the problem then try to check which are the values that are overlapping with the page header. Try to focus on those values and increase/decrease the height or increase/decrease the width of that columns. We followed this procedure to overcome this problem.